# Handling of StatusCallBack when Dialing a Number with Extension

Tags: twilio

When we Dial a Number with `<Dial>` tag, we provide the `<Number>` to which the call should be sent to. We can call an extension using SendDigits. How do we track if the call to the extension has been answered or not answered? Since the number is routed through an exchange, will Twilio always handle only the response of the exchange?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio provides the `DialCallStatus` on the initial answer of the call which is handled by the device managing the extensions.

There isn't eventing available by the device handling the extensions for Twilio to capture, so you are correct, Twilio will only handle the response of the exchange.

Comment: Thanks! Twilio support confirmed the same. Is there any workaround to this? We need to capture the Answer/No-Answer at the extension

Comment: You would need to prompt the dialed party to perform some action, look at Alternatives to AMD (Human Detection) - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132567-Can-Twilio-tell-whether-a-call-was-answered-by-a-human-or-machine-